# Opening a div by clicking a button and closing the same div by clicking another buttonm

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am making a page where there will be three buttons 1) Mission, 2) Vision, 3) Management

Here the functions have to be
1.By clicking the Mission Button a separate div(#mission1) shall open.

2.By clicking the Vision Button another div(#vision1) shall open in the same position of the #mission1 div and also the #mission1 & #mteam divs shall close.

1. By clicking the Management Button another div(#mteam) shall open in the same position of the #mission1 & #vision1 divs and also the #mission1, #vision1 divs shall close. 
   and so on consecutively

I have coded the following
Script

```
$('document').ready(function() {

   $('#show1').click(function(){

     $('#mission1').slideToggle();  


       });

       $('#show2').click(function(){

           $(' #vission1').slideToggle();



           });


           $('#show3').click(function(){

            $('#mteam').slideToggle();   

               });
});
```

CSS

```
 #mission1 
  {
    width:450px; 
    height:200px; 
    background:#069; 
    margin-top:10px;
    display:none; 
    position:absolute; }


  #vission1
  {
    width:450px; 
    height:200px; 
    background:#096;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:none; 
    position:absolute; }

    #mteam
  {
    width:450px; 
    height:200px; 
    background:#CC3;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:none; 
    position:absolute; }​
```

HTML

```
<button id="show1">Mission</button>
<button id="show2">Vision</button>
<button id="show3">Management</button>

         <div id="mission1">Abcd</div>
         <div id="vission1">VVVVVVV</div>
         <div id="mteam">MMMMMMMMM</div>
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amitabhaghosh197/XseGB/)

I have done it but I am facing the problem only the hide issues. My hiding is being operated only after clicking the same buttons but not clicking the other buttons.

Please help me how shall I do this.
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thecodeparadox's answer is very good. But you can use jQuery.data() to get the div id from the button element. If so, you must do like this:

```
<button data-href="mission1">Mission</button>
var currentDivId = $('button').data('href');
```

and then try this code:

```
<button id="show1" data-href="mission1">Mission</button>
<button id="show2" data-href="vission1">Vision</button>
<button id="show3" data-href="mteam">Management</button>

<div id="mission1" class="demo">Abcd</div>
<div id="vission1" class="demo">VVVVVVV</div>
<div id="mteam" class="demo">MMMMMMMMM</div>
```

and the JavaScript code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#show1, #show2, #show3').click( function() {
        var $div = $('#' + $(this).data('href'));
        $('.demo').not($div).hide();
        $div.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks JackingLiu You are Genious. It worked perfectly. Thanks and thanks and also thanks.

Comment: i have changed it in fiddle See the demo.  http://jsfiddle.net/amitabhaghosh197/XseGB/1/

Answer (score 1):

According to your current code:

```
$('#show1').click(function(){
     $('#vision1, #mteam').slideUp();
     $('#mission1').slideToggle();  
});

$('#show2').click(function(){
     $('#mission1, #mteam').slideUp();
     $('#vission1').slideToggle();  
});

$('#show3').click(function(){
     $('#mission1, #vission1').slideUp();
     $('#mteam').slideToggle();  
});
```

But  If you can change markup like this

```
<button class="mission1">Mission</button>
<button class="vission1">Vision</button>
<button class="mteam">Management</button>

         <div class="mission1 common">Abcd</div>
         <div class="vission1 common">VVVVVVV</div>
         <div class="mteam common">MMMMMMMMM</div>
```

and then try this code

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var current = this.className;
  $('div.common:visible').slideUp(function() {
    $('div.' + current).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

would be more easier

Comment: thanks thecodeparadox but i am confused about what shall be the CSS. I am working in CSS but it is not working.  Thanks again